# Iodine formation reaction

Tags: ions

$$\ce{IO3-(aq) + 5I-(aq) + 6H+(aq) -> 3I2(aq) + 3H2O(l)}$$
Why does the reaction between iodide and iodate ions have to occur in an acidic medium ($\ce{H+}$) to form the iodine? what do the $\ce{H+}$ ions react with?

Comment: Well, you may check for yourself that the reaction contains H+ and is balanced. Consequently, without H+ it won't be balanced. Sounds like enough of a reason to me.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more complex per a source ['Kinetics and mechanism of the iodate-iodide reaction and other related reactions'](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224016620_Kinetics_and_mechanism_of_the_iodate-iodide_reaction_and_other_related_reactions), to quote from an article in the journal *Physical Chemistry Chemical Physics* (November 1999):

> The reduction of iodate by iodide, known as the Dushman reaction, is one of the components of the oscillating Bray-Liebhafsky reaction. The large body of work devoted to the kinetics of the Dushman reaction gives seemingly contradictory results. This work analyses and summarizes them and shows that they are special cases of a complicated kinetics and that they can be explained by a common mechanism. This mechanism can be generalized to all the XO3- + Y- reactions (X, Y = I, Br or Cl). They all involve an asymmetric intermediate YXO2.

See reaction system depicted in Equations (8) to (13). Here is a partial discussion of the system from the available PDF to quote:

> The essential hypothesis of this mechanism is the existence of as a definite intermediate species and not as I2O2 an activated complex. Its existence was already proposed in  1930 by Bray [17] in order to explain the classical rate law. We make no distinction between I2O2 and H2I2O3 (I2O2 + H2O) as these two forms are kinetically equivalent. In reaction (12), B~ represents the anion of the buffer....

As to the question on the role of H+, note that the starting Equations (8) and (9) of the system both involve H+, which results in the cited intermediate $\ce{I2O2}$:

> $\ce{IO3- + H+ ⇌ IO3H}$  (8)
>
> $\ce{IO3H + I- + H+ ⇌ I2O2 + H2O}$  (9)

Answer (score 1):

Fabian has proposed that the reaction between the ions iodate $\ce{IO_3^-}$ and iodide $\ce{I^-}$ do not react, because the reaction will produce the ion $\ce{O^{2-}}$ which would not exist in water. This is not a good reason, because in water, $\ce{O^{2-}}$ is immediately transformed into $\ce{OH^-}$.  Of course, Fabian recognized this possibility. But he does not explain why $\ce{H^+}$ ions are necessary in this reaction.

The answer is much simpler. The ions iodate $\ce{IO_3^-}$ and iodide $\ce{I^-}$ do not react without $\ce{H^+}$ because they are both negatively charged, and they repel each other in water. In the presence of $\ce{H^+}$, one may admit that the iodate $\ce{IO_3^-}$ and iodide $\ce{I^-}$ produce temporarily $\ce{HIO_3}$ and $\ce{HI}$ which are neutral and do not repel one another.

Another reason is that $\ce{I_2}$ is not stable in basic solution. It reacts with $\ce{OH^-}$ to produce the inverse of the preceding reaction, i.e.:$$\ce{3I_2}  +  \ce{6 OH^-} \rightarrow  \ce{IO_3^-} + \ce{5 I^-} + \ce{3 H_2O}$$

Answer (score -1):

Omitting the hydrogen ions would lead to
$$\ce{IO3-(aq) + 5I-(aq) -> 3I2(aq) + 3O^2-}$$
but $\ce{O^2-}$ would not exist in water. So an alternative could be to write
$$\ce{IO3-(aq) + 5I-(aq) + 3H2O -> 3I2(aq) + 6OH-(aq)}$$
Basically, the hydrogen ions are there to indicate that the reaction takes place in an acidic solution and hint that access hydrogen ions would improve the reaction kinetics.

The version with the hydroxide ions could be used to emphasize that the reaction would cause an increase of the pH value.